# C# Change a SQL query and a Form1's DGV from another Form2

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I'm wondering what's the best way to change a variable from one Form to another.

I have in Form1 a datagridview that is updated by a sql query and listbox controls. So, when I select items in my From1's listboxes, it changes the sql query that will update the DGV:

```
public void Defaultview()
    {
        string strSQL = "SELECT mycolumn1, mycolumn2 FROM myTable";
        string strWhere;
        string connetionString = @"Data Source=mydatasource;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=SSPI";            
        strWhere = GetListFilter(tableLayoutPanelForm1);
            if (strWhere != null)
            {
                strSQL += " WHERE " + strWhere;
            }
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter= new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, cnn);
        DataTable Dt = DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(Dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Dt;
    }
```

GetListFilter function will loop through all my listboxes and update the strWhere in function of the selectedItems from the listboxes.

```
  public string GetListFilter(Control ctrlContainer)
    {
        string strWhere = null;

        foreach (Control ctrl in ctrlContainer.Controls)
        {
            string strCondition = null;
            // ListBox handling
            if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(ListBox) && ctrl.Name.Contains("CFRA") == true)
            {
                ListBox lb = ctrl as ListBox;

                foreach (var li in lb.SelectedItems)
                {

                    strCondition += $"'{li}',";

                }
                if (strCondition != null)
                {
                    if (strWhere == null)
                    {
                        strCondition = strCondition.TrimEnd(',');
                        strWhere += $"{ctrl.Name.Substring(13)} IN ({strCondition})";
                    }
                    else if (strWhere != null)
                    {
                        strCondition = strCondition.TrimEnd(',');
                        strWhere += $" AND {ctrl.Name.Substring(13)} IN ({strCondition})";
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return strWhere;
    }
```

Ok, now I click on a button1 from this Form1 and make a Form2 appears:

```
private void btn1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Form2 = new Form2(this);
        Form2.Show();
        Form2.TopMost = true;
    }
```

Within this form2, I have two listboxes that I can drag and drop value from the first one to the other. Then I have a button2 in this Form2 and when I click on it, I need to have my strSQL variable (from Form1) changed so that my DatagridView in Form1 can display the right infos.

So my question is: At the end, only the string "strWhere" need to be updated with Form2's listbox selection so should I update my Form1's sql query from Form2 ? Or maybe create a new datatable in Form2 that I send to my DGV in form1 ? Or simply create a new instance of my Form1 when I click on the button of my Form2 but in this case, how can I take into acccount the new selection of my Form2...
I'm a bit confused on how to proceed on this one... Any suggestion would be nice

Comment: It is unclear “what” form 2 is doing to the `strSQL` variable. In reference to the question… _”Should I update my Form1's sql query from Form2”_  ?… since the code is passing the entire form1 to form2 I am not sure what difference it would make “where” you update the sql query. Where is the query executed? Again, it is difficult to understand “what” form2 is “changing” in reference to the sql query.

Comment: @JohnG , Form2 is basically 2 listboxes and 1 button. The first listbox is displaying the entire first column of my datable that I can drag & drop to the second listbox. Then I would click on the button and it'd take the selection I made and use it to refresh the Datagridview I have on Form1

Comment: + the code of GetListFilter so that you can understand how strWhere is built

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something. Form1 is running, the code in form1 calls the method `Defaultview` which executes a query along the lines of … "SELECT mycolumn1, mycolumn2 FROM myTable WHERE XXX"  … the XXX portion is built from the `GetListFilter` method… then … the query is executed and the grid is updated with the results from the query. This is straight forward and I assume this works. THEN, the user clicks a button `btn1` on form1. I assume the posted code is the button `btn1` “click” event. In this event, a new form2 is created and the entire form1 is passed to form2.

Comment: Then you state… _”Within this form2, I have two listboxes that I can drag and drop value from the first one to the other. Then I have a button2 in this Form2 and when I click on it, I need to have my strSQL variable (from Form1) changed so that my DatagridView in Form1 can display the right infos.”_ … This is where I get confused. I assume form2 is “building” a new query from the list boxes on form2. It sounds like you would like to call form1’s `GetListFilter` method again, however, it will use the list boxes from form1 not from form2.

Comment: I assume form2 is creating a “new” query from the list boxes on form2. If this is the case, then I recommend you alter the `Defaultview` method to take a string parameter that is the query you want to execute. This string would contain the “entire” query. Then form1 would need a new method that “creates” this query string from its list boxes and form2 would also have a method to create the query string from its list boxes. This would mean that you would need to remove the `GetListFilter` method from the `Defaultview` method.

Comment: Then in form1, you would build the query using the new method, that calls the `GetFilter` method. Then pass that query string to the altered `Defaultview` method to execute. Then in form2, the code does the same thing, it creates a new query string using its list boxes in form2 and returns this string to form1. After the string has been returned to form1, then have form1 call the `Defaultview` method with the query string from form2. Again, this is speculation on my part and I feel I am missing something.

Comment: @JohnG, thanks trying to sort this thing out. So to answer you, yes you totally understood what's going on. I'm actually not sure to pass the Form1 when crreating the new Form2... But I think I understand what you'd do... kind of separate GetListFilter from Defaultview to have a "generic" Defaultview that is updated by one customized query in Form1 or another customized query in Form2. Ok that's sounds a nice idea but I need to make sure that the Datagridview in Form1. At the end, I have to come back on Form1

Comment: I am just saying that in form1, the method `Defaultview` can ONLY work for form1 because it is calling the `GetListFilter` INSIDE the method. If you pull that portion of code out of the `Defaultview` method and simply “pass in” the FULL query string, then you can call the method using the query string from form1 AND also the query string from form2. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: It is really unnecessary to pass form1 to form2. Instead, in form2, create a “public” `string` variable, call it something like `form2query`, then in form2, build the query from the list boxes, then set that string query to the `form2query` variable. Then in form1, when calling form2, do not pass anything to it but use a `ShowDialog` instead of `Show` Then in form1, you will have something like… `var form2 = new Form2();`   `form2.ShowDialog();` … the code will stop there and wait until form2 is closed.

Comment: After form2 is closed, form1 should be able to get form2’s variable `form2query` like…   `string f2query = form2.form2query` … this is one way to pass data back to form1 from form2.

Comment: @JohnG Thanks for those ideas man ! So I moved forward a bit, I separated the function "GetListFromfilter" from Defaultdaataview (bonus: the response seems faster !). Then, I created the form2query variable in form2 as you suggested. I'm not far ! But now, when runnig step by step the code, I can see that the items I drag&drop into my second listbox are not taken into account as SelectedItems...

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea why the _”second listbox are not taken into account as SelectedItems”_ … It would be a guess on my part as I do not know what code is executing. I suggest you edit your question and ADD this additional information along with any other code changes. IF YOU DO THIS… DO NOT DELETE the original question and code… ADD this additional info UNDER the existing question and code. You can add a header line like “EDIT…” to indicate that the info below was added later. Obviously, you will need to add additional text to describe what the code is doing and what is not working.

Comment: Haha JohnG, that was a silly question,  don't bother I found the trick, if you put items within a listbox, just loop through "Items" instead of selectedItems !
I'll let you know if I figure out my transfer of variable with your way :)

Comment: @JohnG that worked !  Thank you so much :) So basically here is the scheme: use showdialog() instead of show() in the form1. Use a "defaultview" function that just makes the SQL connection and has the "whole" query string as parameter. Use in form1 and form2 two different query constructor functions (one adapted for From1's controls, the others to Form2's controls). Once the string query constructor made the string SQL, pass it in defautview. In form2 use a public string that will be updated and sent to Form1 after Form2 closed using Form2.Querystring within Form1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you need something like this at some point in Form2:

```
    Form1 form1;
    form1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
    if (form1 != null)
    {
        form1.UpdateStuff(var someParam);
    }
```

So, your Form1 is located in the application and then you invoke a public method (UpdateStuff) to do what you need.